# how to combine calculated columns from an initial dataframe to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe(from sql) and need to calculate different metrics from the initial dataframe and then combine them all into the final dataframe.
initial dataframe is
**merged_stats_skuranks_df**.

A result dataframe is
`result_raw = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date_diff','attributes_platform','l2','dau_view', 'dau_click', 'dau_to_cart', 'dau_preorder', 'dau_order', 'dau_ps', 'view'])`

and  my measures look like this

```
               result_raw['dau_click'] = merged_stats_skuranks_df[merged_stats_skuranks_df['dau_click'] == 1].groupby(['date_diff','attributes_platform','l2'])['user_client_id'].nunique()
               result_raw['dau_to_cart'] = merged_stats_skuranks_df[merged_stats_skuranks_df['dau_to_cart'] == 1].groupby(['date_diff','attributes_platform','l2'])['user_client_id'].nunique()
               result_raw['dau_preorder'] = merged_stats_skuranks_df[merged_stats_skuranks_df['dau_preorder'] == 1].groupby(['date_diff','attributes_platform','l2'])['user_client_id'].nunique()
               result_raw['dau_order'] = merged_stats_skuranks_df[merged_stats_skuranks_df['dau_order'] == 1].groupby(['date_diff','attributes_platform','l2'])['user_client_id'].nunique()
               result_raw['dau_ps'] = merged_stats_skuranks_df[merged_stats_skuranks_df['dau_ps'] == 1].groupby(['date_diff','attributes_platform','l2'])['user_client_id'].nunique()
```

but as a result I get the result measures but not groupped columns (example in the picture). groupped columns are empty

[the result pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPbUu.png)

What am I doing wrong and how to combine all this calculated columns to a new df properly.

Also I was thinking to calculated all the measures like this, but I cannot managed to write the right condition in lambda ( as count unique user_client_id if dau_view == 1)

```
result_raw = merged_stats_skuranks_df.groupby['date_diff','attributes_platform','l2'].agg([
    ('dau_view', lambda x: (x.dau_view == 1).nunique()), 
    ('dau_to_cart', lambda x: (x.dau_tocart == 1).nunique()), 
]).reset_index()
```

Sorry it might fairly easy but I am new to python and can't figure out  how to solve the problem.
Appreciate all the help)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning values to a specific column, you can try using `pd.concat()` to combine results.

Try this:

```
# Create an empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Calculate metrics and combine results
for col in ['dau_click','dau_to_cart', 'dau_preorder', 'dau_order', 'dau_ps']:
   temp_df = merged_stats_skuranks_df[merged_stats_skuranks_df[col] == 1].groupby(['date_diff','attributes_platform','l2'])['user_client_id'].nunique().reset_index()
   df = pd.concat([df, temp_df])
```